# Determinant 4x4

Tags: proof-verification, determinant

This looks very simple but I guess I made a mistake somwhere because the result should be 17 
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

First I added  negative 1st row to 3rd
$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$

Then I multiplicate 2nd row times $4$, so the whole determinant will be multiplied with $0.25$.

Then I added 3rd row to the second
$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$

Now I cross 3rd column and 2nd row which would be $4((-1)^5)$ plus the rest which would be $-2(-5)$ = $10$ not $17$
Thanks for help

Comment: The element a31 should be $0$ after first amendment.

Comment: Thanks, I typed it incorrectly, but still the result is what i wrote ..

Comment: You made several minor mistakes. When calculating determinants one must be **very** careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

and then, to the third row, you subtract the first, giving

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

then duplicate 2nd row to get

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

and then, to the 2nd row, add the 3rd, to get

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & -4 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

notice how the last element of the 2nd row now is a $3$.

Using Laplace formula over the 1st column we get

$$1\times \begin{vmatrix}-2 & 0 & 3 \\ -4 & -4 & 3 \\  -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} - 2\times \begin{vmatrix}  2 & 4 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 3 \\ -4 & -4 & 3 \end{vmatrix}$$

Because

$$\begin{vmatrix}-2 & 0 & 3 \\ -4 & -4 & 3 \\  -1 & -1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 2, \begin{vmatrix}  2 & 4 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 3 \\ -4 & -4 & 3 \end{vmatrix} = -16$$

we get

$$0.5\times\left(1\times 2 - 2\times (-16) \right) = 17$$